# get WKT for OSM node, Way and relation for a specific tag

Tags: openstreetmap, sql

How can I obtain semantically correct WKT geometries for a OSM [way](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Way) or [relation](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation) or [node](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Node)?

Well node is simple and way as well, but I am struggling with the relations which can contain many ways:

For example the relation https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/2764083 contains two ways https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/26128247 and https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/205746186#map=18/48.21971/16.35130 which form the border.

However, how can I ensure that when I create a line string the whole (single) border is returned in a semantic correct way? A simple `GROUP BY` then `collect_list` for the ID of the relation on any of the nodes matching can only return the separate relations as `LINESTRINGs`. How could these be merged in the right way or better a proper single geometry be returned in the first place?

I looked at the SQL from https://github.com/mojodna/osm2orc for inspiration but still struggle with the relations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For nodes and ways see https://georgheiler.com/2019/05/07/analyze-osm-data-in-spark/

Only relations are missing from now.